Numpy random 0 and 1 matrix with bias towards 0
Is there a smart, fast way to create an n x n numpy array filled with 0's and 1's with bias towards 0's?
I did np.random.randint(2, (size,size)) but the bias is not accounted for here. I could do for loop but i want a faster cleaner way to populate the matrix. Thanks!

What form does this bias take?

I would use numpy.random.choice with custom probabilities:
n = 10
p = 0.9 # probability of 0s

out = np.random.choice([0, 1], size=(n, n), p=[p, 1-p])

Another option, generating numbers in the 0-1 range, comparing to the probability of 0s and converting the booleans to integer:
out = (np.random.random((n, n))>p).astype(int)

Example output:
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]]


You can use np.random.rand and then check if the values are above a threshold between 0 and 1. This returns a boolean array which can be multiplied by 1 to get an integer array.
1 * (np.random.rand(8, 8) > 0.8)

returns:
array([[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]])

